# Place element at the bottom of the wrapper with height 100%

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap-content1 {
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x600);
  min-height: 100%;
}

.wrap-content2 {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap-content1">
    Wrapper Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-content2">
    Wrapper Content 2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  This is a footer
</div>
```

I want to display the footer div at the bottom of the wrapper div which has a height of 100%.

I know this can be achieved by placing the footer div inside of the wrapper div, but it doesn't meet my requirements.

Comment: You want the text of the footer to appear inside the wrapper, but without the footer being inside the wrapper?

Comment: or padding-bottom to wrapper, negative margin to footer

Comment: @Mr Lister: No i want the footer to appear below the wrapper

Comment: Do you want it to always display at the very bottom or ONLY in the wrapper div? Will your page never have vertical scrolling?

Comment: But the footer IS displaying below the wrapper. The problem in the plunkr is that the wrapper's contents overflow out of it, being higher than the wrapper itself. You should fix that first.

Comment: @Nihal please pay attention while editing .. why did you add extra  CSS ? don't understand why your edit got approved ...

Comment: sry that was mistake on my part i was trying to change that but my internet was not working so my edit wasn't changed.

Comment: @Nihal and since you placed the code inside snippet remove unecessary text like `here is my CSS` which has no more meaning  .. so please don't make his question irrelevant and create confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want the `wrap-content1` to be full height so use `vh` unit and you will avoid all the `height:100%` and thus no more overflow issue:

```css
body,
html {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap-content1 {
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x600);
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.wrap-content2 {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap-content1">
    Wrapper Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-content2">
    Wrapper Content 2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  This is a footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your calculation is not right for .wrap-content1 and it makes the footer does not place at the bottom of .wrapper. You set height of .wrapper = 100%, but .wrap-content1 and .wrap-content2 are more than 100% of parent, this makes the .wrapper cannot wrap 2 children. When I set

```
.wrap-content1 {
    background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x600);
    min-height: 87%;
}
```

I can put the footer at the bottom of wrapper.

Comment: how come the value `87%` ?

Comment: yes, but as more contents are added to the wrapper div this will fail.

Comment: this value is just example. the explanation is above.

Comment: @khoi: yes your explanation is absolutely correct, sorry somebody else downvoted